# Calculate rotation of a point set

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

I have a set of 2D coordinates of fingers on the screen (e.g. $x_1$;$y_1$, $x_2$;$y_2$ etc) before the rotation was done. Fingers are moved to the new coordinates ($x'_1$;$y'_1$, $x'_2$;$y'_2$). I'd love to calculate an angle of the performed rotation in the range $[0;2\pi)$

The best I have is the following algorithm:

1. Calculate the coordinates of the center of the point set (e.g. $\frac{x_1+x_2}{count}$;$\frac{y_1+y_2}{count}$)
2. Calculate an euler angles between the x-axis and the vectors from the center found on the previous step to every point, so I have 'starting' angles to every point in range $[0;2\pi)$
3. Every time fingers move, recalculate the angles, substract them from the original angles to get the 'deltas'
4. Sum all the deltas from the previous step and threat them as the angle of the rotation

The problem is that the rotation appears to be faster in count times, where count is the number of points I have.

I cannot simply divide the deltas because they change from $0$ to $2\pi$ independetly from each other. If I divide $0$ to count, I get $0$, but when I divide $2\pi$ to count, I get, let's say $\pi$ which is not correct.

I suppose I need to normalize the angles to $(-\pi;+\pi)$ at some point to avoid that behavior but I cannot find the correct way of doing this.

Here is what I mean:
[image]
In this particular case I can easily sum angles' deltas and divide them by the number of points, but in common case that division is not possible because of the seam between 2$\pi$ and 0

Comment: To be clear, is each "finger" just a point? And are all the points rotated by the same angle around the same center of rotation? If yes, do you already know what the center of rotation is, or do you need to find that too?

Comment: finger is just a point (x;y), all coordinates are absolutely random. I calculate the geometrical center at the step 1 and use it as the center of a rotation

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am looking for. I have original point coordinates and I have the new point coordinates I want to find an angle between them

Comment: Maybe an illustration would be useful?

Comment: Sure, I've tried my best in illustrating the task and added the image to the post

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! But to be honest, I'm not quite sure how to tackle the problem then...

Comment: This seems related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem

Comment: There are couple of ways to do it. May be this will be the easiest to explain - The lines through the points have a slope - you could use this to calculate the tangent of the angel   as difference between the two slopes that are tangent of the lines' angel with the x axis.

Comment: @Moti That was my original intent! But I have two indexed sets of slopes before and after and the MAIN problem is that I cannot convert the set of slopes into a single slope because summarizing them and division by the count does not work. If I summarize slopes only, it works without glitches, but the rotation appears to be n-times faster than expected.

Comment: What are those dai's? Calculate the rotation amount which is IDENTICAL around o. May be you need to find o?